# Transaction Denial of Service

Tags: transactions, attack

If the BTC network can only only handle on average 2,759 transactions per block.

During a period where whales attempt a mass dump, could they essentially perform a DoS attack where they make a large number of transactions with higher miner fees than normal, to block unsuspecting network peers from also dumping their coins.

This would allow them to have higher potential gains if they are the only ones who can make a transaction in a 10 minute period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a part of [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory#:%7E:text=Game%20theory%20is%20the%20study,systems%20science%20and%20computer%20science.) that was designed for protecting bitcoin, if some whales want to spend 10 000 satoshis per bytes spamming transactions for 1 month it is gonna cost them a lot of money, and nothing prevent someone from paying 10 001 satoshis per bytes so that its transaction is mined allowing him to dump forcing the other whales to now spam 10 002 satoshis per bytes and more.

It is also worth noting that whales have an incentive to protect the bitcoin network because they depend on it and anything rendering the network suspicious will lower the price.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Technically that is not part of an attack as the mempool filters are not bypassed. It is up to each node whether to accept a transaction into mempool dependant on transaction validity but also other factors which may include the fee sat/byte.